# Pandas: проверка верхней строки на идентичность нижней стоке

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Имеется [датасет](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_JujeCgQHsqeHvm4RvVzNOXFIo9LZ_cH/edit#gid=1172943935)

В столбце "А" построчно перечислены дубли имен объектов, в последующих столбцах указаны свойства каждого объекта.
Код должен работать по следующему алгоритму:
Если в столбце "А" одинаковые значения, то сравнить свойства 2-х значений в столбце "B", если они разные, то в новый столбец записать слово "difference", если одинаковые — то ничего не записывать.
Пример:
[image: 123.PNG]

Следующий код работает некорректно:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx')



    attr1 = (df.duplicated('name', keep=False)) & (~df.duplicated('feature1', keep=False))
    df.loc[attr1, 'diff_feat1'] = 'diff_1'

    attr1 = (df.duplicated('name', keep=False)) & (~df.duplicated('feature2', keep=False))
    df.loc[attr1, 'diff_feat2'] = 'diff_2'

    df.to_excel('2.xlsx')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну а файл с данными где?

Comment: @Дух сообщества  1) смотрим в столбце А дубли ли 1 2 строка? Если да, проверяем в столбце Б 1 и 2 строка дубли? если да проверяем столбце С, если нет, то создаем столбец Diff_feat1 и в 1 и во 2 строке записываем строку "diff_1". если и в столбце B и в C полные дубли как и в A первых 2 строчках, то ничего не делаем. Дальше смотрим в столбце А  3, 4 строка дубли? ДА - идем проверять на дубли 3, 4 строчки в столбце B и С

Comment: @strawdog  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_JujeCgQHsqeHvm4RvVzNOXFIo9LZ_cH/edit#gid=1172943935

Comment: К датасету нет доступа. и у вас с первой колонке обязательно идут дубли парами или нет?

Comment: @strawdog Sorry, доступ открыл. В первой колонке обязательно идут дубли парами. исключений нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в общих чертах все делается довольно просто: если у вас в первом столбце гарантированно значения идут парами и эти пары *уникальны*, то:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", usecols=[0,1,2])
# берем из датафрейма только столбцы с исходными данными
```

затем делаем группировку и проверяем ваши условия:

```
res = pd.DataFrame() # результирующий датафрейм
for i, g in df.groupby("name"):
    if g["feature1"].is_unique:
        g["diff_feat1"] = "diff_1"
    if g["feature2"].is_unique:
        g["diff_feat2"] = "diff_2"
    res = res.append(g, ignore_index=True)
```

теперь res будет:

```
     name                         feature1                           feature2 diff_feat1 diff_feat2
0   first                some staff of one                  some staff of one     diff_1        NaN
1   first  Feature - not some staff of one                  some staff of one     diff_1        NaN
2  second             some staff of second               some staff of second        NaN        NaN
3  second             some staff of second               some staff of second        NaN        NaN
4   third              some staff of third                some staff of third        NaN     diff_2
5   third              some staff of third  Feature - not some staff of third        NaN     diff_2
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, товарищ!